# Mysql/python fetchall() can't handle result because it is too big

Tags: python, mysql, bigdata, database

I have a table of 2,760,000 rows. In mysqlworkbench, it takes 36 sec to select * from original table.

I want to create another table using this existing table in python (using **my_func()** to convert values).

But, when I run it in the command line, it never seems to finish.

```
sql = "SELECT ID, Eye, Values FROM my_original_table"
curQuery.execute(sql)

for row in curQuery.fetchall():        
    dat = list(row)
    id = dat.pop(0)
    eye = dat.pop(0)
    values = dat.pop(0)     
    v = my_func(values)
    if v != None :
        sql = "INSERT INTO new_table VALUES ( '%s', '%s', %d );" % (id, eye, v)
    print(sql)
    curExe.execute(sql)

db.commit()
```

However, if I added **LIMIT 0,10** to my first select sql (like below), it runs fine. So, this means my program is right. But does this mean without the 'Limit', the data is too much for my computer to handle? How can I solve this?

```
sql = "SELECT ID, Eye, Values FROM ETCEpisodeVisualAcuity LIMIT 0,10"
```

Comment: BTW, never construct SQL with string formatting; use parameterized queries. (In many of the Python SQL libraries, you can fix this in your code simply by removing the single-quotes around the %s in your query and replace the last % with a comma)

Comment: 2.7 million rows do not sound **that** many, right?

Comment: BTW if you have an index in `new_table` it gets rebuilt after *every* insert. This takes time.

Answer (score 5):

Use cursor as iterator (without calling `fetchall`):

```
sql = "SELECT ID, Eye, Values FROM my_original_table"
curQuery.execute(sql)

for row in curQuery:
    # ...
```

above is equivalent to process a query using while loop with `fetchone`:

```
curQuery.execute("SELECT ID, Eye, Values FROM my_original_table")
row = curQuery.fetchone()
while row is not None:
  # do something with data...
  row = curQuery.fetchone()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your solution is easier for me to read. After I tried it, the program finally prints out some results. Then I actually found a bug in my 'my_func()'. However, after I fixed the bug, it does not print any results on the command line again. Then I moved db.commit() into the loop where insert is. Then the print finally works. after 30 seconds, I can see 40,000 rows are created in new table

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples):

> db.store_result() returns the entire result set to the client
>   immediately. If your result set is really large, this could be a
>   problem. One way around this is to add a LIMIT clause to your query,
>   to limit the number of rows returned. The other is to use
>   use_result(), which keeps the result set in the server and sends it
>   row-by-row when you fetch. This does, however, tie up server
>   resources, and it ties up the connection: You cannot do any more
>   queries until you have fetched all the rows. Generally I recommend
>   using store_result() unless your result set is really huge and you
>   can't use LIMIT for some reason.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(yourhost,yourname,yourpw,yourdb)

db.query("SELECT ID, Eye, Values FROM my_original_table")

r=db.use_result()

>>> r.fetch_row()
(('3','2','0'),)
```